# Setup Apache web server for local testing

Tags: java, apache, web-applications, apache2, webserver

I have Apache2.2 installed locally
What are the steps to setup the same as a web server for local testing?

Like where to copy local files, what path to update, etc

Comment: Please be more specific, apache is a web-server already, now you have to setup your `VirtualHost` and to enable it you need to `restart apache`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make virtual host see file `apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` [examples of configuration](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html) ..

For complete migration see [Apache migration HOWTO](http://www.trt24.gov.br/arq/migration.html)